# Extracting the values from a xml url

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I need to print the values inside Identificador tags from this Url https://clip.unl.pt/sprs?lg=pt&year=2013&uo=97747&srv=rsu&p=1&tp=s&md=3&rs=8145&it=1030123459, but I get no output at all.

```
function get_xmlcontent(StdClass $data)
{
    $year       = $data->year;
    $course     = $data->clipid;
    $typeperiod = $data->typeperiod;    

    if ($typeperiod == 's'||$typeperiod == 'a') {
        $period = $data->period;
    } else if ($typeperiod == 't') {
        $period = $data->trimester;
    }

    //file from CLIP
    $xmlUrl = 'https://clip.unl.pt/sprs?lg=pt&year='.$year.'&uo=97747&srv=rsu&p='.$period.'&tp='.$typeperiod.'&md=3&rs='.$course.'&it=1030123459';

    $xmlStr = download_file_content($xmlUrl);
    $xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
    foreach ($xmlObj->unidade_curricular->inscritos->aluno as $aluno) {
        echo $result = $aluno->identificador;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your custom download_file_content() function, i used file_get_contents() and passed the xml string on to SimpleXMLElement. Hope that points you in the right direction.
Consider splitting the functionality in two methods: a) buildURL() b) fetchXMLContent().

```
$xmlContent = file_get_contents('https://clip.unl.pt/sprs?lg=pt&year=2013&uo=97747&srv=rsu&p=1&tp=s&md=3&rs=8145&it=1030123459');
$xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlContent);

foreach($xmlObj->unidade_curricular->inscritos->aluno as $aluno){
    $result= $aluno->identificador;
    echo $result;
}
```

To answer your comment: that involves another problem!
Your domains is a HTTPS domain, so you need to tell cURL how to handle that.
I've created an example, which solves all the mentioned problems and demonstrates
cURL usage.

```
<?php

function buildURL($year, $period, $typeperiod, $course)
{
    return 'https://clip.unl.pt/sprs?lg=pt&year='.$year.'&uo=97747&srv=rsu&p='.$period.'&tp='.$typeperiod.'&md=3&rs='.$course.'&it=1030123459';
}

function doRequest_with_FileGetContents($url)
{
   return file_get_contents($url);
}

function doRequest_with_cURL($url) {
  $ch=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

  // your domain is a HTTPS domain, so you need to tell curl how to deal with SSL verifications
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

  $data=curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  return $data;
}

function processXML($xmlContent)
{
   $xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlContent);

    foreach($xmlObj->unidade_curricular->inscritos->aluno as $aluno){
       $result= $aluno->identificador;
       echo $result;
    }
}

// Ok. Lets test..

// some testing values, i guess these will come from a formular
$year = '2013';
$period = '1';
$typeperiod = 's';
$course = '8145';

// a) build URL
$url = buildURL($year, $period, $typeperiod, $course);

// b) fetch content
$content_a = doRequest_with_cURL($url);

$content_b = doRequest_with_FileGetContents($url);

// c) process content (should be the same)
echo "\nRequest with cURL\n";
processXML($content_a);

echo "\nRequest with file_get_contents()\n";
processXML($content_b);
```

Comment: Thank you that helped. I've tried to build a curl function to fetch me the url info, however, i cant seem to relate it to the fetchxml function.

    function get_url($year,$period,$typeperiod,$course){

$ch=curl_init();
$timeout=5;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://clip.unl.pt/sprs?lg=pt&year='.$year.'&uo=97747&srv=rsu&p='.$period.'&tp='.$typeperiod.'&md=3&rs='.$course.'&it=1030123459');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$data=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}

Comment: i updated my initial answer, with an example for cURL usage. if you like it, accept the answer as correct. thanks

Comment: Thank you. Processing xml by file_get_contents is ok, but by curl gives me errors.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in C:\moodle25\server\moodle\local\ecoclipaluno\somefile.php:217 Stack trace: #0 
C:\moodle25\server\moodle\local\ecoclipaluno\somefile.php(217): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1
C:\moodle25\server\moodle\local\ecoclipaluno\somefile.php(235): processXML(false) #2 {main} thrown in C:\moodle25\server\moodle\local\ecoclipaluno\somefile.php on line 217

    $xmlObj= new SimpleXMLElement($xmlContent);