# XML Url parameters+REST

Tags: php, xml, rest, moodle

A little more than a month ago I did a post involving the extraction the values of from a URL.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231390/extracting-the-values-from-a-xml-url

It was a good answer and helped me a lot, but is there a way to generalize the code for any parameter given?  The testing parameters won't be part of a formula, and this plugin I'm developing is supposed to be handled by Moodle teachers. They won't have access to my code to manually alter the parameters themselves. Here is the [link](https://clip.unl.pt/sprs?lg=pt&year=2013&uo=97747&srv=rsu&p=1&tp=s&md=3&rs=8145&it=1030123459).

By changing the **rs** parameter, I change the course. **p**(even/odd) and **tp**(semestral/anual/trimestral courses) parameters are about semesters and **year** is the year.

This is what I currently have.

```
function buildURL($year, $period, $typeperiod,$course)
{
    return 'https://clip.unl.pt/sprs?lg=pt&year='.$year.'&uo=97747&srv=rsu&p='.$period.'&tp='.$typeperiod.'&md=3&rs='.$course.'&it=1030123459';
}

function doRequest_with_FileGetContents($url)
{
    return download_file_content($url);
}

function processXML($xmlContent)
{
    $xmlObj= new SimpleXMLElement($xmlContent);
    $result=array();

    foreach($xmlObj->unidade_curricular->inscritos->aluno as $aluno)
    {
        $result[]= $aluno->identificador;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Testing parameters:

```
$year='2014';
$period='1';
$typeperiod='s';
$course='8145';

$url=buildURL($year,$period,$typeperiod,$course);
$content_b = doRequest_with_FileGetContents($url);
$dataClip = processXML($content_b);
```

I've tried to associate the id number of the course (course / course edit Settings/course id number) to the parameter **rs**, by typing:

```
$course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id'=>$courseid), '*', MUST_EXIST);
$idnumber = $course->idnumber;
```

and replace it in `$url=buildURL($year,$period,$typeperiod,$idnumber);` but the XML doesn't even process. Is this even possible to pull it off without a formal interface?

Comment: you are aware that you could write your test.php to also use `$_GET[]` variables instead of constant values? If not, then you are now ;-)

Comment: @ Najzero  What do you mean? the link I provided is just an example. The parameters are not static. Specially those four that I mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried adding: echo $url;  to your code, to see what URL is generated by the buildURL function call? (This might explain what is going on when you tried to get the idnumber from the course record). I assume you've also got debugging on ( http://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging )

Comment: I don't understand why are you talking about REST... By REST the service should build the links, not the client....

Comment: @davosmith It generates the intended URL. So, $course->idnumber is recognized. The parameter **rs** is working. Now for the other three, I see in Moodle'db that there are no columns of day/month/year. I could use that structure to request the correct year and semester. I suppose the field 'TimeCreated' concerns about the calendar? A long string of numbers. Is there a way to convert them to month/year?

Comment: It normally is possible to convert a long string of numbers into month/year. Most likely it's a UNIX Timestamp, see http://php.net/DateTime object, it's constructor and the `@` notation to pass a timestamp to the ctor.

Comment: Just to confirm - Moodle uses UNIX timestamps for all dates / times, so hakre is correct to suggest the use of the DateTime object

Comment: Thank you Davo and Hakre, followed your advices and it's working.